# Sort DataGrid Rows After Removing Grouping through XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

SUMMARY: After removing grouping have items in a data grid sort.

So I currently have a project with a user control that displays one of two controls depending on a datatype. Now when that control is a DataGrid, I have set up a style on the template that uses grouping.

```
<!--STYLE used to add grouping & expanders to data grid-->
  <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
              <Expander IsExpanded="False" >
                 <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                 </Expander.Header>
                 <ItemsPresenter/>
              </Expander>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

And it's set up in the model like this so that the grouping is done on a property called "Group".

```
Data = new ListCollectionView(rows);
Data.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
```

Now the user can toggle a toggle button to remove headings, and therefore just show a list of values.

```
public bool IsGrouped
{
   get { return isGrouped; }
   set
   {
      isGrouped = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      if (ConfigurationModel != null)
      {
         if (IsGrouped == true)
            (ConfigurationModel as ConfigurationKeyPairModel).AddGrouping();
         else
            (ConfigurationModel as ConfigurationKeyPairModel).RemoveGrouping();
      }
   }
}

public void RemoveGrouping()
{
   if(Data.GroupDescriptions.Count > 0)
      Data.GroupDescriptions.RemoveAt(0);
}

public void AddGrouping()
{
   if(Data.GroupDescriptions.Count < 1)
      Data.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
}
```

Once the grouping has been removed the item's go back to how you'd expect just a normal data grid. But they're still in the same positions they would have been in if they were grouped. I don't want to have the user manually click column headers(which are hidden anyway) I'd like to have this data sort itself straight away. I've had a look around for the past hour but haven't found any decent solutions that are MVVM or don't just have the user click column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the `CollectionView` by a property by adding a `SortDescription` to its `SortDescriptions` property:

```
public void RemoveGrouping()
{
    if (Data.GroupDescriptions.Count > 0)
        Data.GroupDescriptions.RemoveAt(0);
    Data.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    Data.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PropertyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

If there are no `SortDescriptions` added, the sort order is effectively undefined.

Comment: Thank you, Don't know how I missed it, but I think seeing most posts using the XAML version of CollectionView threw me off. Thankyou!